# How can I specify environment for Spock test?

Tags: grails, spock

How can I specify test environment for specific Spock test other than default one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can use the spock framework via command like (http://grails.org/plugin/spock, see Running Tests section), like this:

```
grails test-app :spock
```

you should be able to specify the environment as well, pretty much like this:

```
grails [environment]* test-app :spock
```

because the test-app script allows environment option.

Let me know if this works for you. :)

EDIT:

As you noticed me, the solution above applies for every test in your application. In order to annotate every single test for a specific environment, I think you should have a look at this plugin:

http://www.grails.org/plugin/spock-grails-env-extensions

Comment: Thanks, but this solution will set custom environment for all spock tests. I wanna set custom environment for only my `SuperSepcificSpec` test and for other ones use default env.

Comment: Is possible to configure using `@Annotation` inside spec? I think custom run script is not best solution for me

Comment: I edited the answer, hope the plugin I linked you is actually what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you. This exactly what I was looking for. Unfortunately current version of plugin doesn't work with Spock v0.6 =(

Answer (score 0):

> Thank you. This exactly what I was looking for. Unfortunately current
>   version of plugin doesn't work with Spock v0.6 =( – fedor.belov Aug 22
>   '12 at 10:52

It works, you just have to comment dependsOn out (using Spock v0.7).

https://github.com/osoco/grails-spock-env-extensions/blob/master/SpockGrailsEnvExtensionsGrailsPlugin.groovy

Comment: I asked the developer to update that and he did. spock-grails-env-extensions (v0.2) plugin does work again.

Comment: Another way arround to make it work is to delete the lane I mentioned, zip that plugin, put it into lib and add it as dependency into BuildConfig